# Grammar: Did Jim ask you whether you are a virgin? VS Did Jim ask you whether you were a virgin?

Tags: tenses, backshifting, past-vs-present

How do I form a question based on the following details:

At 1pm on Sunday
Jim: Are you a virgin?
Jane: Yes

### *nothing happened from 1pm to 9pm*

At 9pm on Sunday: Did Jim ask you whether you were a virgin?

or

At 9pm on Sunday: Did Jim ask you whether you are a virgin?

Comment: In English, the 1st person pronoun "I" is always capitalised - no exception.

Comment: **Were** is the correct sentence to use, since the speaker is **asking** about Jim's knowledge.  Asking has **doubt** in it.

Comment: **Time has nothing to do with it**

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The difference is [the mood](http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOflinguisticTerms/WhatIsMoodAndModality.htm)

One is subjunctive (**were**) and the other is indicative (**are**)

While both sentences are indeed grammatically correct, the mood is completely different.  A subjunctive mood suggests that there is doubt.

> If you were a virgin | *subjunctive*

vs

> If you are a virgin | *indicative*

### Subjunctive

The first sentence expresses the **uncertainty** of Jane's virginity.  The same concept goes for these sentences

- If I had one million dollars ...
- If I were rich ...
- If cats were people ...

Using the million dollar sentence as an example, it's very clear that the subject does not have a million dollars, and there is usually a conditional phrase that follows, but that's another beast on it's own.  You have to use the conditional because the first statement is in fact subjunctive.

> If I had one million dollars, how *would* I spend it?
>
> If fish could walk, fishing would be quite easy.
>
> If a tree fell in the woods, would it make a sound?
>
> If the student had read the book, he would have passed.

### Indicative

The root word here is *indicate*, which means to point something out, to demonstrate an actual, factual action... or being.

> I have one million dollars

By using the indicative mood, there is no uncertainty, and there would be no need to use conditional phrases afterwards..  you cannot say

> If I have one million dollars, how would I spend it? **INCORRECT**

The sentence would be the epitome of a grammatically incorrect sentence.  It is very clear from the sentence that I *do* have one million dollars, no doubt whatsoever, no hopes, nothing..

> If I have one million dollars, I will spend it. **CORRECT**
>
> If a tree falls in the woods, does it make a sound?

Any doubt would be expressed in subsequent sentences.

> John : Jim, I just heard that you won $1 Million!
>
> Jim  : John, if I have a million dollars, *then where is it*?

---

**Can you spot the subjunctive sentence?**

> If cats are people, then why can they not talk?

or

> If cats were people, then they could talk.

Comment: I think the subjunctive sentence is "If cats were people, then they could talk."

Answer (score 0):

Here "Did Jim ask you whether you **were** a virgin?" is correct because here we are [backshifting](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21835/what-is-backshifting-as-applied-to-english-grammar) the tenses (to past).

The reason of backshifting in your sentence is that the sentence starts with **Did** (past).

Also check out [Sequence of tenses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_of_tenses)

Answer (score 0):

Both the answers are correct. In reported speech, backshifting is exceptional if the statement still holds true. For instance:

> Mandy: *“The sun rises in the east.”*
>    Mandy said that the sun ***rose*** in the east. 
>    **or**
>    Mandy said that the sun ***rises*** in the east.
>
> John: *“My brother is at Leipzig university.”*
>    John said that his brother ***was*** at Leipzig university. **or**
>    John said that his brother ***is*** at Leipzig university.

see. [Additional Information](http://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/reported.htm)

Comment: This is the correct answer.