# Grammar: “Thought”

Tags: british-english, quotation-marks, backshifting

I saw this sentence in a composition and I don’t know whether it is grammatically correct:

> He is so cute, I thought.

Firstly, since the whole composition is in *past tense*, is it correct to use “is” here?

Secondly, do thoughts need to be in quotation marks, i.e.

> “He is so cute,” I thought.

Comment: Also this: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/21835/191178

Comment: The 'straight' (involving actual speech) quote structure is well known: "He is so cute," I said. (For completeness, some say that the comma is not absolutely essential nowadays, especially with an inverted speech tag such as << [,] said John. >> And there are different conventions  preferring comma placement (if the comma is opted for) within or outside the inverted commas. With thoughts, inverted commas are optional. Some prefer italics << _He is so cute_ I thought. >> and the comma again considered optional by some. However, _some_ form of offsetting is needed, _at least_ comma or italics.